# aws codebuild create-project - Invalid JSON received

Tags: json, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

Iam trying to make copies of an existing codebuild project with the exported json via aws cli via the below command

```
aws codebuild batch-get-projects --names "test-build" > test-build.json
```

and post modifying the json, trying to create a new codebuild project from the below command

```
aws codebuild create-project --cli-input-json file://test2-build.json
```

but getting

> Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON received.

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "name": "PPOPOBuild",
        "arn": "arn:aws:codebuild:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:project/ppppBuild",
        "source": {
            "type": "CODECOMMIT",
            "location": "https://git-codecommit.xxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxxxxxxx",
            "gitCloneDepth": 1,
            "gitSubmodulesConfig": {
                "fetchSubmodules": false
            },
            "insecureSsl": false
        },
        "secondarySources": [],
        "sourceVersion": "refs/heads/master",
        "secondarySourceVersions": [],
        "artifacts": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "demo4cicdbucket",
            "path": "ok",
            "namespaceType": "BUILD_ID",
            "name": "xxxxxxxBuild",
            "packaging": "ZIP",
            "overrideArtifactName": true,
            "encryptionDisabled": false
        },
        "secondaryArtifacts": [],
        "cache": {
            "type": "NO_CACHE"
        },
        "environment": {
            "type": "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER",
            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8",
            "computeType": "BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM",
            "environmentVariables": [],
            "privilegedMode": false,
            "imagePullCredentialsType": "SERVICE_ROLE"
        },
        "serviceRole": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/service-role/codebuild-Procurement-Module-01-Build-service-role",
        "timeoutInMinutes": 60,
        "queuedTimeoutInMinutes": 480,
        "encryptionKey": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:xxxxxxxx:alias/aws/s3",
        "tags": [],
        "created": "2021-04-20T15:51:21.008000+05:30",
        "lastModified": "2021-04-21T11:53:51.283000+05:30",
        "badge": {
            "badgeEnabled": false
        },
        "logsConfig": {
            "cloudWatchLogs": {
                "status": "ENABLED"
            },
            "s3Logs": {
                "status": "DISABLED",
                "encryptionDisabled": false
            }
        }
    }
],
"projectsNotFound": []
```

}

I even tried passing the single JSON object instead of the array but still getting same error like below

```
{
        "name": "PPOPOBuild",
        "arn": "arn:aws:codebuild:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:project/ppppBuild",
        "source": {
            "type": "CODECOMMIT",
            "location": "https://git-codecommit.xxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxxxxxxx",
            "gitCloneDepth": 1,
            "gitSubmodulesConfig": {
                "fetchSubmodules": false
            },
            "insecureSsl": false
        },
        "secondarySources": [],
        "sourceVersion": "refs/heads/master",
        "secondarySourceVersions": [],
        "artifacts": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "demo4cicdbucket",
            "path": "ok",
            "namespaceType": "BUILD_ID",
            "name": "xxxxxxxBuild",
            "packaging": "ZIP",
            "overrideArtifactName": true,
            "encryptionDisabled": false
        },
        "secondaryArtifacts": [],
        "cache": {
            "type": "NO_CACHE"
        },
        "environment": {
            "type": "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CONTAINER",
            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8",
            "computeType": "BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM",
            "environmentVariables": [],
            "privilegedMode": false,
            "imagePullCredentialsType": "SERVICE_ROLE"
        },
        "serviceRole": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/service-role/codebuild-Procurement-Module-01-Build-service-role",
        "timeoutInMinutes": 60,
        "queuedTimeoutInMinutes": 480,
        "encryptionKey": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:xxxxxxxx:alias/aws/s3",
        "tags": [],
        "created": "2021-04-20T15:51:21.008000+05:30",
        "lastModified": "2021-04-21T11:53:51.283000+05:30",
        "badge": {
            "badgeEnabled": false
        },
        "logsConfig": {
            "cloudWatchLogs": {
                "status": "ENABLED"
            },
            "s3Logs": {
                "status": "DISABLED",
                "encryptionDisabled": false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says it needs to follow the same format given by following the command.

`aws codebuild create-project --generate-cli-skeleton`

From What I see there from your JSON there are no `created` and `lastmodified` fields in the skeleton. "arn": "arn:aws:codebuild:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:project/ppppBuild" shouldn't be there too

Answer (score 0):

remove the following elements from that json, and format appropriately.

```
-"projects": []
-"lastModified": 
-"created":
```